# SEM 4 questions - testing linearity, sum score, number of variables, independent variables

Tags: spss, structural-equation-modeling, amos, linearity

For my master thesis I'm making a structural equation model.
However, I do not have much experience with this. So here are some different questions.

1. I read that one of the assumptions important for SEM is: Linearity: A linear relationship is assumed between endogenous and exogenous variables.
   However, I see in other papers that this is only considered for the sum score of a latent variable. But not for 'normal/other' variables, such as age. Does this have to be done?
2. In addition, I never intended to make a sum score of my variables, is this always the case?
3. I only have 86 respondents, because I have a very specific population and because of time limitation. Does this mean that I can only have 86/10 = 8 variables in total in my SEM model? Or does this mean that I may have 5 variables per latent factor? I find conflicting information.
4. Is it possible to include 'independent' variables in a SEM model, such as car ownership. So not link this to a latent variable, or is that not possible?

Thank you in advance!

Regards,

Comment: Linearity just means that the arrows in the path diagram represent linear (as opposed to curvilinear or nonlinear) effects. If age has a curvilinear effect on your latent variable, a standard SEM will not be able to model that, and your model will be misspecified. It has nothing to do with sum scores.

Answer (score 0):

welcome to CrossValidated!

1. I'm not sure quite what you mean by this. You assume linearity, but it's often impossible to test.  I don't know what the sum score of a latent variable is.
2. It's not always the case, but if you're going to make a sum score, why have a latent?
3. Whoa! That's a *really* small sample size. It's going to be hard to say anything interesting in SEM with a sample that small, however many variables you have.
4. I'm not sure what you're getting at here. What is this variable doing if it's not linked to a latent variable? (You can have SEMs with no latent variables  though, so I think the answer is yes.)